# How do I convert a json date format to the following dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: jquery, json, date

I've seen other examples but I am looking for this specific format if possible?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format JSON Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-json-date)

Comment: these examples do not have dd/mm/yyyy format, well the one they do have doesnt work

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick format from JSON date format to required date format using jQuery:

For a JSON date string like:

```
/Date(1339439400000)/
```

try:

```
var newFormattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(Date(your_JSON_date_string)));
```

and it will result in date like this:
09/14/2012

Comment: datepicker just to parse date ?

Answer (score 6):

```
    function formatJsonDate(jsonDate) {
        return (new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)))).format("dd/mm/yyyy");
    };    

    var testJsonDate = formatJsonDate('/Date(1224043200000)/');

    alert(testJsonDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "json date format". json only returns strings.

Date javascript object can parse a variety of formats. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

You can do:

```
var myDate = new Date(myDateAsString);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few suggestions in the answers to this post -- [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-json-date)

If those examples aren't working, you can just format it manually.  Here's a quick fiddle that demonstrates it -- http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/KqyDv/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //set up my JSON-formatted string...
    var myDate = new Date(2011,2,9);
    var myObj = { "theDate" : myDate };
    var myDateJson = JSON.stringify(myObj);

    //parse the JSON-formatted string to an object
    var myNewObj = JSON.parse(myDateJson);

    //get the date, create a new Date object, and manually format the date string
    var myNewDate = new Date(myNewObj.theDate);
    alert(myNewDate.getDate() + "/" + (myNewDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + myNewDate.getFullYear());
});
```